# C# column increment in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

Is there any way to do an increment number from 1,2,3 and so on for my column in my datatable?

For example similar to column "Code" below

[image: expected output]

or at least is there any other way that i can name the numbers manually?

Here's what I've tried (but not working)

```
        DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        column.AutoIncrement = true;
        column.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        column.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
```

Thanks for your reply

Comment: You mean when you add rows to table, this column value is not auto incremented? What do you mean by not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AutoIncrement` is indeed the right approach here. You might be missing something else, but the following code does work:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { ColumnName = "Code", AutoIncrement = true, DataType = typeof(int) });
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { ColumnName = "Resource Type", DataType = typeof(string) });
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { ColumnName = "Number of hits", DataType = typeof(int) });

var newRow = dt.NewRow();
newRow[1] = "Testing";
newRow[2] = 3;

dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

var newRow2 = dt.NewRow();
newRow2[1] = "Testing 2";
newRow2[2] = 6;

dt.Rows.Add(newRow2);
```

And when inspecting `dt`, the result is:

```
Code   Resource Type    Number of hits
0      Testing          3 
1      Testing 2        6
```